# Running Fink Application advice (outside of IDE of course)

Tags: apache-flink

I'd be happy to take on board any advice on running Flink Applications as it seems to be a bit of a minefield. I'm talking Linux here (Centos 7 dist) as I don't even want to share the issues that Windows throws back at me.

Running from the command line is just one long disaster, it just never seems to run. Initially, I tried doing it 'properly' via maven with a lib folder for the jars and config folders for properties files etc, this was a disaster as it will never find anything (when started via java - jar ..). I then tried the maven shade plugin to get an uber jar (and it sure is uber in every sense of the word) - but he dies as well as Flink cannot finds its own Parameter tool dependency. (also, note either of the above could care less if you use -Dlog4j.configuration.file as it just ignores it altogether). Thus, we abandon anything to do with java -jar anApp.jar
Moving on, we try submitting it via the web interface. This at least shows promise (ie does actually find the ParameterTool) but it soon dies very quickly. It seems the upload puts it (and deletes it on failure so it difficult to tell really) into the /tmp directory and from there, any configuration classes or support classes that my application needs are invisible as Flink just never finds them. So it crashes (and brings the web application down with it and so I have to start from scratch reloading the uber jar and resetting all my command line options again. (on the bright side, I do not need to put my -Dlog4j argument in as it gets ignored here as well).

Any advice welcome...

Answer (score 3):

> (when started via java - jar ..)

well this right here is a big red flag.

In contrast to running jobs in the IDE, where you just run the main method of your class, to run the job outside of the IDE it must be submitted to a Flink cluster instead. The reason is that in the IDE a cluster is automatically started upon job execution for convenience, but outside the IDE you generally want to re-use an existing cluster.

Given that you were able to access the web-interface I will assume that you already started flink using `/bin/start-cluster.sh` or `/bin/start-local.sh`. If not, now's the perfect time to do it.

To submit your job, run `/bin/flink run <your jar>` . Any library that your application requires, *that is not already included in the jar*, must be placed into the `/lib` directory of the flink distribution.

Note that i would suggest to first submit the bundled wordcount example (/examples/batch/WordCount.jar), so you don't have to deal with dependencies right away. (Let's solve one issue at a time)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that Ches. Did indeed abandon java -jar altogether. Managed to make significant progress by sort of cheating on the cluster, although still not ideal. Basically, added a command line argument (which is available on the web interface) that allowed me to hard wire the location of a properties file to be picked up via the ParameterTool. This  config file would then contain the location of the support resources so the application would run happily.  I did though have to add a bit of extra code into the application to determine whether it was on windows or Linux so that it could then pick out the right format of the hard coded location from the config file. Ideally of course, as I put the files in /src/main/resources in the first place, I thought Flink  would find them by itself on either platform (or at least defer to the java to find them as normal) but it does not. Hard coded (ish it is at least a configurable hard location via the properties file) will do for now.

Comment: in 1.3.3 and 1.4 you can load a properties file into the ParameterTool like this: `ParameterTool pt = ParameterTool.fromPropertiesFile(MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/my/resource"));` Obviously replace `MyApplication` with your class name if running in a static context, or `getClass()` in a non-static context. Implemented in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7630.